# Помогите с менее затратным методом итерации матриц в python

Tags: python, циклы, матрицы

*Потею над следующей задачей с codewars. Специально не ищу ответов, так как сам хочу разобраться.*

Дана матрица в виде вложенного списка :

`a = [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]`

Цель: проитерировать матрицу разными способами ( то есть сверху-вниз, справа-налево и т.д.). Но, решение задачи должен подходить и для очень больших матриц, как указано ниже:

`[range(10,10+10**10),range(20,20+10**10),range(30,30+10**10),range(40,40+10**10]`

Каким способом мне проитерировать такую матрицу что бы быть наименее затратным по памяти, так как мое решение ниже через цикл for выдает memory error:

```
  import numpy as np
DIRECTION_UP, DIRECTION_LEFT, DIRECTION_DOWN, DIRECTION_RIGHT = range(1,5)

class Table:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.datatr = np.transpose(data)
    def walk(self,dir0,dir1):
        result = []
        if dir0 == DIRECTION_RIGHT:
            if dir1 == DIRECTION_DOWN:
                for i in np.arange(0, len(self.data)):
                    for j in np.arange(0, len(self.data[i])):
                        result.append(self.data[i][j])
                return result    
            elif dir1 == DIRECTION_UP:
                for i in np.arange( len(self.data)-1, -1, -1 ):
                    for j in np.arange(0, len(self.data[i])):
                        result.append(self.data[i][j])
                return result
        if dir0 == DIRECTION_LEFT:
            if dir1 == DIRECTION_DOWN:
                for i in np.arange(0, len(self.data)):
                    for j in np.arange(len(self.data[i])-1, -1, -1):
                        result.append(self.data[i][j])
                return result
            elif dir1 == DIRECTION_UP:
                for i in np.arange( len(self.data)-1,-1,-1 ):
                    for j in np.arange(len(self.data[i])-1, -1, -1):
                        result.append(self.data[i][j])
                return result
        if dir0 == DIRECTION_UP:
            if dir1 == DIRECTION_LEFT:
                for i in np.arange( len(self.datatr)-1, -1, -1 ):
                    for j in np.arange(len(self.datatr[i])-1, -1, -1):
                        result.append(self.datatr[i][j])
                return result    
            elif dir1 == DIRECTION_RIGHT:
                for i in np.arange(0, len(self.datatr)):
                    for j in np.arange(len(self.datatr[i])-1, -1, -1):
                        result.append(self.datatr[i][j])
                return result
        if dir0 == DIRECTION_DOWN:
            if dir1 == DIRECTION_LEFT:
                for i in np.arange( len(self.datatr)-1,-1,-1 ):
                    for j in np.arange(0, len(self.datatr[i])):
                        result.append(self.datatr[i][j])
                return result
            elif dir1 == DIRECTION_RIGHT:
                for i in np.arange( 0, len(self.datatr)):
                    for j in np.arange(0, len(self.datatr[i])):
                        result.append(self.datatr[i][j])
                return result
```

Comment: Что в данном контексте вы понимаете под "проитерировать"? В классическом варианте сама по себе итерация не требует какой-то значительной дополнительной памяти. Приведите ваш код, на котором у вас возникает проблема. И ещё приведите ссылку на само задание на codewars.

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5af5c18786d075cd5e00008b собственно, само задание

Comment: Но вы же в вашем коде не итерируетесь, а составляете полный список элементов в определённом порядке. А в задании явно указано, что нужен **ленивый** итератор. Почитайте про специальные методы, в частности про `__iter__` и `__next__`

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю, что такое "транспонировать матрицу".  Я знаю, что такое "Найти дискриминант"...

А что означает "проитерировать матрицу"?

Если это означает всего лишь "перебрать все элементы", то в чём проблема?

Сверху вниз, слева-направо с:

```
a = [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]

for k  in  range(0, len(a)-1):
    line = a[k]
    for j in range(0, len(line)):
         elem = line[j]
         print("elem[{0},{1}] = {2}".format(k, j, elem))
```

Снизу вверх, слева-направо с:

```
for k  in  range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
    line = a[k]
    for j in range(0, len(line)):
         elem = line[j]
         print("elem[{0},{1}] = {2}".format(k, j, elem))
```

Я уж дальше не буду - лень... :-) Но я так и не понял, причём тут **память**?

Comment: Да, вы правы, мне нужно перебрать все элементы, это решение у меня есть. Но, оно не проходит, так мне нужен именно способ, который подойдет для очень больших матриц как эта - [range(10,10+10**10),range(20,20+10**10),range(30,30+10**10),range(40,40+10**10]. Традиционный метод здесь влечет за собой memory error.

Comment: @Velidoss Дело не в том, что метод плохой, а в том, что 40000 списков просто НЕ ВЛАЗЯТ в память!